# Why do I get an access violation when setting the value of an IHTMLInputTextElement?

Tags: delphi, access-violation, ihtmldocument2

I get the following error:

> Access Violation at address 0050AA07 in module "project1.exe". Read of address 00000000.

I'm trying to auto fill a form in TWebBrowser. It's just a field called 'login' on a form.

What does it mean? How do I solve it?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  frm: IHTMLFormElement;
  fld: IHTMLInputTextElement;
begin
  doc := webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  frm := doc.forms.item(0, EmptyParam) as IHTMLFormElement;
  fld := frm.item('login', EmptyParam) as IHTMLInputTextElement;
  fld.value := 'someone';
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are dereferencing a pointer that is set to `nil` and the code that is attempting this illegal act is located at `$0050AA07` in your process.

If you can't solve it from this, then if showed us the code we could tell you why your pointer is set to `nil`.

Comment: Which line raises the error? You can discern this by running under the debugger.

Comment: If you step over the code, what line triggers the AV? (or what line is located at $50AA07)

Comment: i'm sorry im not sure how to do that. im using delphi 2010

Comment: @ployo60 set a breakpoint on begin and then use step over F8 to execute the code one line at a time. Have you really never used the debugger before? That's a really crucial skill to learn.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint by placing your cursor on the line in question (begin) and press F5.

Comment: yeah the error is at the line when i try to fill in the field with the word someone.

Comment: @ployo60 The problem then is that `fld` is nil.

Comment: ah, I like this debugger. thanks for that. How can i solve the fact that fld is nil? Its obtained from the html.

Comment: @ployo60 `frm.item` is not finding the login field. I can't really help you there, I've no idea what's in your document. By the way, you now have enough reputation to up-vote.

Comment: well what if you just take the site 'mail.com' cuz it seems to work for 'gmail.com'

Comment: @ployo60 There presumably isn't an item with that name in the first form of that document.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is it since when I inspect the code of the html I find this: <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="text"

Comment: @ployo60 That's now a different question. I'm not really an expert on DOM, IHtmlDocument2 etc. However, I have answered your original question. If you want to ask another question about why `frm.item` returns nil that would be good, but I honestly believe I've answered this question.

Comment: @ployo60 You should accept answers to your questions. Not just this one, but all but one of your other questions has an answer that I consider very acceptable. I realise that you are quite new here, but please take a read of the FAQ. A lot of people have given up their time to help you. Accepting and up-voting good answers is how you return the favour. Doing so will encourage people to answer you in the future.

Comment: yeah you are right, thank you. Just need to understand the answer on my last question better. but I'll be looking out for all the features on the site more. If i miss something, you are more than welcome to give me another kick! thx