# Why doesn't my code find the login form field from mail.com?

Tags: html, delphi, input, field

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984116/why-do-i-get-an-access-violation-when-setting-the-value-of-an-ihtmlinputtexteleme) showed that `fld` in the following code is `nil`.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  doc: IHTMLDocument2;
  frm: IHTMLFormElement;
  fld: IHTMLInputTextElement;
begin
  doc := webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  frm := doc.forms.item(0, EmptyParam) as IHTMLFormElement;
  fld := frm.item('login', EmptyParam) as IHTMLInputTextElement;
```

I have a TWebBrowser that goes to mail.com and I am wondering why `frm.item` returns `nil`. It leads me not being able to fill in the field. On a different website, for example gmail.com, it does work when I fill in instead of 'login' - 'email'.

I am pretty sure the name of the field is 'login' because I can find this from the page's HTML: `<input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="text" ...>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to my own oh so stupid question is pretty straight forward. If you replace the 0 with a 2. It does work, because there are multiple forms on the page and the specific field 'login' is in form 2 of the html page

Comment: You might wish to skip searching for the *form* altogether. Just search for the item with an ID of *login*. The `id` attribute is guaranteed to be unique on a page, so if that's the ID of the input field you need, then you can get it directly without regard for how many other forms are on the page. That's what [GolezTrol's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985373/finding-which-form-the-input-field-belongs-to-delphi/4985395#4985395) suggests when it mentions [`IHTMLDocument3::getElementFromID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752543.aspx).

Comment: Yes I agree and I understand. but I think if I try to place text in a field I need to know the form name as well, correct? this is the code for placing it: 'fld.value:=GetFieldValue(theForm,'test@gmail.com');' So i need to know what form the id belongs too so I fill it in.