# finding which form the input field belongs to delphi

Tags: delphi, forms, input, browser

Follow my previous question which i managed to answer myself. I am able to place text in an input field on a website served on webbrowser in a delphi application. sometimes there are multiple forms on a website, most of the time its around 2, but it could head up to a faire few. Now my question is. How can I 'test' or find out which form the selected input field belongs. Lets just take an example. For example, gmail.com there are 2 input fields: 'Email' and 'Passwd' I also know that there are 2 forms on this site. with code like this one you can select either one of them :

```
doc:=webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
frm:=doc.forms.item(0,EmptyParam) as IHTMLFormElement;
fld:=frm.item('Email',EmptyParam) as IHTMLInputTextElement;
fld.value:=GetFieldValue(theForm,'test@gmail.com');
```

by changing the 0 to a 1 in the second line you have the second form on the site. Now I want to know how can I let the program find out for itself which form the input field belongs too. could you do this with try? or anything else? Any have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`fld.form` points to the form the element belongs to. You can use `doc.getElementFromId` or any other method you like to get the element without using the form to get it, although it is easiest if it has an id.

Other option is to search through all forms to check if it has a field with the given name, but that won't help you if a field exists in more than one form.

Comment: @ployo you need to use `IHTMLDocument2` instead of `IHTMLDocument3`, e.g. `FBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument3`.

Comment: do you mean as IHTMLDocument2? and is that for doc.getElementFromId?

Comment: got them wrong way round, you need 3. I only worked that out by searching in the import unit. You can use search too.

Comment: e.g. `(Browser.Document as IHTMLDocument3).getElementFromId('my_id')`

Comment: delphidabbler.com/tips/56 is this where you got it from?

Comment: how come this does not do the trick??form:=fld.form('login',EmptyParam) as IHTMLFormElement;

Comment: no i dont get an error anymore. but It does not work either. btw I added .item after fld.form..... But what my code above does is work from document into form in field. Is it not possible to work from field to form?? It seems so simple but it does not work

Comment: I can't tell from a distance. If you don't get errors, something must go right. But if you don't get the output you want, you should check each step. Try to check (by name, by innerHTML, ...) if fld is the right object, if fld.form is the right object, if a field 'login' actually exists in that form. I got here no page and only 4 outdated lines of your code and you're really providing too little information. If you use the debugger or just show some properties while running, it should be possible to pinpoint exactly what is wrong. And if you don't understand why you can ask here again.